# Use class in differents task on ESP8266 - CPP

Tags: c++, class, multitasking

I'm actually programming on esp8266.
I'm using multitasking and I would like to access a class from any task.
About the building I'm using PlatFormIO so I'm not manage the build.

Here is my main.cpp file :

```
#include "HackQuarium.h"

class LedShowTask : public Task {
public:
    void loop() {
        // some stuff
    }
} ledShowTask;


class WeatherTask : public Task {
public:
    void loop() {
        // some stuff
    }
} weatherTask;

class LightTask : public Task {
public:
    void loop() {
        // some stuff
    }
} lightTask;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Scheduler.start(&ledShowTask);
    Scheduler.start(&weatherTask);
    Scheduler.start(&lightTask);
    Serial.println(F("SETUP"));
    Scheduler.begin();
}
```

And here is my class which is in HackQuarium.h file :

```
class AllStaticData {
    public:
        static t_API_current_weather    currentWeather;
        static t_HackQuarium_data       hackQuariumData;
};
```

I think I need to create a "global" instance of my class to access it from all my tasks, but I don't find how to do it.

If I create an instance in my setup() function, I don't see how to pass it in my tasks :/

Thanks you

Comment: This isn't about multitasking, or the ESP8266... it's about building your program correctly. Present a [mcve] including build steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you declared static attributes, but you didn't define them. It should be:

File.h

```
class AllStaticData {
    public:
        t_API_current_weather   currentWeather;
        t_HackQuarium_data      hackQuariumData;
};
```

File.cpp

```
t_API_current_weather AllStaticData::currentWeather;
t_HackQuarium_data AllStaticData::hackQuariumData;
```

You can also call the constructors that you want when defining those two:

```
//using some example variable
std::string X_class::value("Hello");
```

EDIT:
you should have one .h file and one .cpp file for your class; in the .cpp you include the .h and define static variables outside any function

BUT:
You want to access static data members from some parallel tasks, so you don't have to create an instance of the class, simply access the members using the name of the class. Yeah, you need to sync the access to avoid that some task reads while another writes.

Your problem is not about passing instances of the class, because all members are static.

Comment: Thanks you, I'm agree with you but where do I put 2 declarations in my main.cpp file ? In the setup() funciton ? outside any function ?

Comment: THANK YOU ! :) that's now working, but I needed to put currentWeather and hackQuariumData in static in my class in .h file